# Remove Google maps markers by click button again using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use geocoding to allow the user to navigate to a specific place and then add markers in a specific radius to this navigated point. If the user clicks on the button again and wants to navigate to another place it should remove all the markers of the first request. I have to say that the navigated point is marked with a blue marker and the others are marked with a red marker. I use this code to do it:

```
// global
var previousTarget = 0;
var markers = new Array(); // All my markers are stored here
// end global

geocoder.geocode(
    {'address': address},
    function(results, status){          
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
            });

            var marker, i;
            var splitted = locations.splitted(",");

            for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++){
                geocoder.geocode(
                    {'address': splitted[i]},
                    function(results, status){
                        if(results != null){
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location
                            });

                            markers.push(marker);
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i){
                                return function() {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: 'myfile.php',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: {addrData: jqXHR.responseText},
                                        success: function(datas, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                            for(var l = 0; l < markers.length; l++){
                                                if(marker == markers[l]){
                                                    infowindow.setContent('test');
                                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },

                                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                            alert("Error");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            })(marker, i));
                        }
                    }
                );

                if(previousTarget > 1){ // Here is the function to click the button twice
                    markers.setMap(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

If I do this there comes an error in the console by hitting the button twice:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'setMap'`

And if I change `markers` to `marker` it just removes the blue marker. Can someone please give me a hint where I made an error?

Comment: More info for MrUpsidown's answer available here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through your markers array and remove each marker.

```
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {

    markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: Just realized I probably should have put that as a comment, why would you need to iterate through each (not being funny, just unsure if I've missed something).

Comment: Because each `marker` is an object on which you need to call `setMap(null)` to remove it from the map. Here `markers` is only an array that holds these objects.

Comment: Thank you, I did a bit of research and found the link I posted in the comments above which establishes your answer. Must learn to think before typing :)

Comment: Thank you, works almost perfect. It doesn't remove the last 2 markers. You know what the reason could be?

Comment: No. Edit your question and add the code you have now. Or even better, create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)