# how to hide google map markers by a button?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map. I created some markers, but I can not hide these markers. I looked at [this document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove). I have one function, but it failed.

```
function LoadMap () {
  var markers = JSON.parse('<%=Stations() %>');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), mapOptions2);
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map2,
      title:"Hello",
    });
    (function (marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        icon: InitIcon
      });
    }(marker, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: You hide a merker using `marker.setMap(null)`.

Comment: I tried by marker.setMap(null) but failed.Where I must use marker.setMap(nulll) ?

Comment: Initially try to clean your code's spacing and syntax errors

Comment: When do you want to remove your markers? On which action?

Comment: As stated above, your code contains errors. Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21333635/1238965

Comment: Duplicate of [remove google maps markers...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333453/remove-google-maps-markers-by-click-button-again-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `setMap(null)` to your Array of markers.

If your `markers` variable contains all your markers, you need to loop through each markers and delete each of them using

```
markers[i].setMap(null);
```

as shown on [your sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)

BTW, your code contains somme errors, like a missing `;` after `var data = markers[i]`